# Cannot add element to json array laravel

Tags: arrays, json, laravel

I want to add new element to Json array but I can't

`{"1":"One","2":"Two","3":"Three"}`

to :

```
{"1":"One","2":"Two","3":"Three","4":"four","5":"five"}
```

in table I determine data with json for using it for array :

```
Schema::create('items', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('title');
    $table->json('data')->nullable();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

in model :

in controller define new data and save it to item table as see data is detemine by array but for adding new element I don't know how define it:

```
class Item extends Model
{
    
    protected $fillable = [
        'title', 'data'
    ];


    protected function data(): Attribute
    {
        return Attribute::make(
            get: fn ($value) => json_decode($value, true),
            set: fn ($value) => json_encode($value),
        );
    }
}
```

in controller :

```
    public function index()
    {
        $input = [
            'title' => 'Demo Title',
            'data' => [
                '1' => 'One',
                '2' => 'Two',
                '3' => 'Three'
            ]
        ];

        $item = Item::create($input);

        dd($item);

    }
```

Itried different way for solving my problem but it doesn't work

Comment: and how did you try to add an element to the `data` array?

Comment: $items['data'] = ['4'=>'four'];
        array_push($item['data'],$items['data']);

Comment: Why you don't use array cast?

Comment: i can find it and solve the problem with using array

Comment: $arr1 = $item->data;
        $arr2 = ['4'=>'four','5'=>'five'];
        $arr3 = $arr1 +$arr2;

        $item->update([
            'data'=>$arr3,
        ]);

        dd($item);

Answer (score 0):

i can find it and solve the problem with using array

```
    $arr1 = $item->data;
    $arr2 = ['4'=>'four','5'=>'five'];
    $arr3 = $arr1 +$arr2;

    $item->update([
        'data'=>$arr3,
    ]);

    dd($item);
```